# My first machine learning experiment , model not converging , tips?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

I wanted to recreate the model mentioned in this paper:https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.09204v1.pdf . I am using keras with tensorflow backend, and a gtx 1050ti.

I am an ML beginner, and thought this would be a good way to get a hands on feel for things. However, My model is not converging(loss is same as first epoch).
This is what I read from that paper:

> The first convolutional layer re- ceives an input of 56px by 56px
>   images with RGB channels. It uses 32 filters of size 5×5×3, stride 1
>   and then sampled with max pooling of size 2 × 2, stride 1. The second
>   convolutional layer has 64 filters of size 5×5×32, stride 1 and a max
>   pooling of size 2 × 2, stride 1. The results of the second max pooling
>   provide the first fully-connected layer with a vector of length 12,544
>   (14 × 14 × 64) which are used by 512 neurons. The final
>   fully-connected output layer uses a 20-wide softmax [21] which
>   represents the probability of each respective 20 class labels. This
>   architecture is similar to the LeNet model [3], but with using
>   rectified linear unit (ReLU) [22] activation functions instead of
>   sigmoid activation functions. We also use dropout [23], a technique to
>   prevent overfitting, with a keep probability of 0.5 for the
>   fully-connected layers.

and my code is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='same', input_shape=(70,52, 3))) model.add(Activation("relu")) model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='same')) model.add(Activation("relu")) model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten()) model.add(Dense(output_dim=512)) model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=2))
model.add(Activation("softmax")) model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=70, batch_size=500,verbose=1)
```

the full code can be found here : https://gist.github.com/harveyslash/5c98f9fdab0d53a2a48f477a52d8588d
I have scrapped the data from goodreads
Help appreciated !

**EDIT**

I forgot to actually ask what i wanted. Since its my first experiment, i would like to ask what are some things that I should do to make my model converge.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Stochastic Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) optimizer with a learning rate decay and [nesterov momentum](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v28/sutskever13.pdf). You can also try a different `batch_size`. Also you are missing drop out layers between the fully connected layers which the authors used.

Try

```
...
# flatten the conv layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# fully connected 512
model.add(Dense(output_dim=512)) 
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# fully connected output layer
model.add(Dense(output_dim=2))
model.add(Activation("softmax")) 

# compile
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer=SGD(lr=10e-4, 
                            decay=10e-6, 
                            momentum=0.99, 
                            nesterov=True), 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# train
model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
          nb_epoch=70, 
          batch_size=64,
          verbose=1)
```

In my experience this usually helps a lot. If you get this setting to converge, you may try `rmsprop` and `adam`.

Comment: Adding the extra ReLU after the flatten is doing nothing. The layer being flattened already has had that nonlinearity applied and `relu( relu(x) ) == relu(x)`

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can go wrong. But the first thing I would check is the learning rate. Adam can be initialized with  learning rate which isn't shown in your code. You could probably try setting a lower learning rate, say, 10e-4, first.